# Acts_as_tree finding file location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, acts-as-tree

I wonder how to use the available methods to find the location of the file in a folder.
For building breadcrumbs, this is easy. We can do

```
<% if @current_folder %>
<div class="breadcrumbs">         
    <% if @current_folder #checking if we are under any folder %> 
        <%= link_to "Home", root_url %> 
        <% @current_folder.ancestors.reverse.each do |folder| %> 
            » <%= link_to folder.name, browse_path(folder) %> 
        <% end %> 
         »  <%= @current_folder.name %> 
    <%# else #if we are not under any folder%> 

    <% end %> 
</div>
<% end %>
```

but, what if i list all the files and want to show where they were created in a folder.
something like:
New File.txt =========== home/first
Second File.pdf ======== home/first/second

How to get this??